# Converting C++ Variant pbVal to byte array in dotnet

Tags: c#, c++, variant

I am trying to refactor some C++ code to dotnet (c# or vb).  The C++ code makes use of the Variant type and uses the pbVal after it has been passed through a call into a COM object.   Here is the salient portion of the C++ code:

```
long bufSize;
int width, height;
VARIANT var;

TCHAR tc[32];
::GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_RESOL_X)->m_hWnd, tc, 12);
width = _ttoi(tc);
::GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_RESOL_Y)->m_hWnd, tc, 12);
height = _ttoi(tc);

m_dlgVideo.m_tvsLive.GetSnapshot(m_dlgVideo.m_lCurChID, lCompression, width, height, &var, &bufSize);

CFile oWrFile;
oWrFile.Open(_T("C:\\temp\\test_asbuffer.jpg"), CFile::modeCreate | 
    CFile::modeReadWrite);

oWrFile.Write(var.pbVal, bufSize);
oWrFile.Close();
CoTaskMemFree(var.pbVal);
```

My confusion (lack of knowledge) has to do with passing the C++ Variant into the GetSnapshot call.  My assumption is that after the call the Variant (var) would return as an array, but it returns just as a single byte value (255). 
In Dotnet I have tried passing var in as Object, Byte, or VariantType and get the same result each time (single byte value of 255).  If I try to pass in an array (e.g. Object[] or Byte[] or Variant[]) the method complains and says ***Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Byte[]'***

My dotnet code looks like this

```
System.Byte imgVar = 0;
long imgSize = 0L;

try {
    axTVS.Snapshot(iTVSID, 50, false);
    axTVS.GetSnapshot(iTVSID, 50L, 400, 225, imgVar, imgSize);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //catch error and handle here

}
```

The imgSize returns with what appears to be a valid size for an array (13,559), but that pesky imgVar is just the one byte (255).  As I said - attempting to pass in a byte array fails.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

My assumption (likely flawed) is that the var should come back as a byte array that is image data - which I can then convert to an image easily enough.

Comment: What makes you think you're supposed to pass in anything for imgVar at all, other than the address of a variable for it to write a result to?

Comment: I can see that's what is happening in the C++ code (e.g. &var passes in a pointer to the var variable) - but I have not found a way to do this in dotnet.  Because dotnet is managed code it doesn't want you to be passing pointers around. If there is no way to use the COM component method in dotnet then thats just a shame.